# Disabling standard styles in lightning

Tags: css, slds

I am using lightning design system for a salesforce1 app.
I want to make the checkbox and radio button look like same as in the design system. But when I apply the lightning design system css class the standard class overrides it.

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Possible work-around is to remove the style sheet dynamically in the rendering of the app.

This solution is described in the answer of [Lightning Design System is overridden by styles from app.css](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93148/lightning-design-system-is-overridden-by-styles-from-app-css/96077#96077)

Let me know if it worked!