# ui:inputCheckbox and lightning design system

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to apply styles for checkboxes from Lightning Design System in my custom Lightning component. I would like to use `<ui:inputCheckbox>` standard lightning component, but looks like not all standard Lightning components compatible with Lightning Design System.

In the SLDS doc there is a statement regarding checkboxes:

> The ability to style checkboxes with CSS varies across browsers. To ensure that checkboxes look the same everywhere, we use a custom DOM. Pay close attention to the markup, because all elements must exist for the styles to work.

And the example from doc looks like this:

```
<label class="slds-checkbox" for="checkboxSample1">
    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkboxSample1" />
    <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
    <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox Label</span>
  </label>
```

But `<ui:inputCheckbox>` tag generates following html code:

```
<div class="uiInput uiInputCheckbox">
  <label class="uiLabel-left uiLabel">
    <span>Reimbursed?</span>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="uiInput uiInputCheckbox">
</div>
```

**So my question - Is it possible to use standard lightning checkbox component and style it with SLDS styles?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible work-around is to remove the style sheet dynamically in the rendering of the app.

This solution is described in the answer of [Lightning Design System is overridden by styles from app.css](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93148/lightning-design-system-is-overridden-by-styles-from-app-css/96077#96077)

Let me know if it worked!