# Lightning Component Styling on UI Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system, slds

I'm wondering why my ui:button components aren't rendering correctly.

This is what the button is supposed to look like

[image: correct style]

but when I try to style the ui:button component it looks like this:

[image: ugly button]

the actual markup for the button is:

```
<ui:button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-col--bump-left" press="{!c.back}">Edit</ui:button>
```

Am I forgetting something?

Edit: so to help clear some things up both pictures are from the exact same button in my app.  The first image was created with `<button>`, the second is `<ui:button>`.  I'm wondering why the styles changed when i switched from button to ui:button.

Comment: Have you tried applying any styles yet?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for the idea! i'm confident i _could_ fix it that way... i dunno. it just feels... wrong? like i shouldn't have to and i'm missing something.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not familiar enough with lightning to judge that, but I'm sure someone will come along and help out.

Comment: When you say not rendering correctly what is different ? You have used --neutral which has to renders with grey border and white background, not sure what I if am missing something here

Comment: @Rao in the first example the button has a flat styling. This is what I want. the second example has a heavy border/shadow -- It looks strange with the rest of the stylings.  At first I prototyped the screens with standard HTML elements like <button> but when i switched over to <ui:button> the extra styling was added.  the --neutral style is what I want but as you can see by the second example something else is happening.

Comment: This might be related to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93148/lightning-design-system-is-overridden-by-styles-from-app-css -- the actual CSS generated at runtime was picking up styles from app.css. That thread indicates that the issue was fixed by using a later version of SLDS.

Comment: @shannonsans Thanks for the link.  I'm using lightning out so maybe that has something to do with it? I have `includestandardstylesheets` set to false on the VF page and I have the latest version of the SLDS from github included as a static resource.

Comment: @RossBassett You say you are using the component with Lighting Out. It might have to do something what that. I've noticed different behavior of styles depending on where I run the component. If it is in it's own app, it looks terrible, but when I put the component in a Lightning record page (you can see the difference in the URL: it has one.app in it) it renders perfectly fine like the SLDS. Some of the SLDS need a certain hierarchy of style classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So,

I brought this up with salesforce support.  They couldn't provide a good answer. After spinning my wheels for a while i switched over to:

`<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-col--bump-left" onclick="{!c.back}">Edit</button>`

lessons learned: avoid ui components.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth you can see a comprehensive list of all the styles added to the `ui:button` component here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/button/buttonFlavors.css

There's one sort of brute-force solution I used to just wipe out these styles, not with `ui:button` but with another component... I made my own component that does nothing but inherit from the ui element but I set all its custom CSS attributes to "inherit". So for ui:button it would look like this:

neutralButton.cmp:

```
<aura:component extends="ui:button">
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

neutralButton.css:

```
.THIS{
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    text-decoration:inherit;
    text-align:inherit;
    border-radius:inherit;
    border:inherit;
    border-top:inherit;
    background:inherit;
    background:inherit;
    box-shadow:inherit;
    text-shadow:inherit;
}

.THIS:hover,
.THIS:focus,
.THIS.is-selected{
    background:inherit;
    background:inherit;
    text-shadow:inherit;
}

.THIS .label{
    white-space:inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
.THIS:hover .label,
.THIS:focus .label{
    color: inherit;
}
.THIS:disabled{
    cursor:inherit;
    background:inherit;
    box-shadow:inherit;
    text-shadow:inherit;
}
.THIS:disabled .label{
    color:inherit;
}
.THIS:disabled .label:hover{
    color:inherit;
}
```

And then use a `c:neutralButton` instead of a `ui:button` and it no longer hijacks the SLDS styles. Still it's a little silly that this ends up being the only reliable way to shut off hard-coded component styles.