# Remove base styles from lightning component framework to use LDS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

Adding a ui:button in Lightning Component Framework results in classes
*uiButton--default* and *uiButton* being added.

In order to use Lightning Design System, I need to remove these classes (or override the CSS styling for these classes). I'm using LDS classes *slds-button* *slds-button--brand*.

I can't see an obvious way to turn off all default LCF styling in order to use LDS. Although I can see responses on a [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93148/lightning-design-system-is-overridden-by-styles-from-app-css) indicating this has been resolved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In init method you can do like this. Find the button by Id. Use aura:id

```
<ui:button label="New Milestone" press="{!c.newMilestone}" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" aura:id="newmilestonebutton" />

var newbutton = component.find('newmilestonebutton');
$A.util.removeClass(newbutton, 'uiButton--default uiButton');
```

Or do the same thing in afterRender() method in Renderer file. You have to override the afterRender() method.

Comment: Thanks Jai. I was hoping for a more standard solution - similar to the *standardStylesheets="false"* option in Visualforce pages. There must be a way to use LDS without having to individually remove every LCF class in javascript?

Comment: This worked quite nicely for us and very easy to implement. Also, the solution is still self-contained in the component. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I posted an idea here: [Lightning Component Styling on UI Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127318/lightning-component-styling-on-ui-components/127521)

Also unpalatable for its own reasons but it works. Will paste it below.

For what it's worth you can see a comprehensive list of all the styles added to the `ui:button` component here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/button/buttonFlavors.css

There's one sort of brute-force solution I used to just wipe out these styles, not with `ui:button` but with another component... I made my own component that does nothing but inherit from the ui element but I set all its custom CSS attributes to "inherit". So for ui:button it would look like this:

neutralButton.cmp:

```
<aura:component extends="ui:button">
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

neutralButton.css:

```
.THIS{
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    text-decoration:inherit;
    text-align:inherit;
    border-radius:inherit;
    border:inherit;
    border-top:inherit;
    background:inherit;
    background:inherit;
    box-shadow:inherit;
    text-shadow:inherit;
}

.THIS:hover,
.THIS:focus,
.THIS.is-selected{
    background:inherit;
    background:inherit;
    text-shadow:inherit;
}

.THIS .label{
    white-space:inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
.THIS:hover .label,
.THIS:focus .label{
    color: inherit;
}
.THIS:disabled{
    cursor:inherit;
    background:inherit;
    box-shadow:inherit;
    text-shadow:inherit;
}
.THIS:disabled .label{
    color:inherit;
}
.THIS:disabled .label:hover{
    color:inherit;
}
```

And then use a `c:neutralButton` instead of a `ui:button` and it no longer hijacks the SLDS styles. Still it's a little silly that this ends up being the only reliable way to shut off hard-coded component styles.

Comment: Now this is clever! I've just called mine button instead of neutralButton, as I plan to use this in place of ui:button going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning contains base components in the lightning namespace, one of these is button. It is recommended in [introducing base lightning components](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_base_lightning_components.htm) that where there is a matching ui and lightning namespace component that you use the lightning namespace.

```
<lightning:button label="Submit" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.clickEvent}"/>
```

In the above example the button will render without the uiButton classes.