# Lightning Components in Visualforce - datepicker, icon style inconsistency

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, lightning-design-system, date-picker

Based on trailhead module or documentation:

- [Lightning Components Basics Trailhead Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_forms)
- [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/qs_aotp_app_step2_cmp.htm)

I have added lightning component to visualforce page:

`$Lightning.use("c:expensesApp", function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:expenses",
        {AccountId : {!$CurrentPage.parameters.AccountId}},
        "lightning",
        function(cmp) {
            console.log("Component created!");
            console.log(cmp);
    });
});`

I am using newest LDS `$Resource.SLDS202`

Is working as expected but I see that there are few major CSS issues which are accepted without comment in both, documentation and trailhead module:

DatePicker field style as a part of the component built in trailhead module:

[image: DatePicker field style as a part of the component built in trailhead module]

I expected to have styles consistent with lightning experience:

[image: lightning experience date picker styles]

Similar issue with time picker:

From the documentation:
[image]

versus lightning experience:
[image]

What does it mean? Am I missing something or should I avoid ui components as per:

[Lightning Component Styling on UI Components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127318/lightning-component-styling-on-ui-components)

Is there any road map for ui components?

Answer (score 2):

I have recently created a datepicker component.[Here](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2016/08/build-lightning-date-picker) is the blog post about it. The blog contains code and implementation instructions. Unfortunately no timepicker.

**Some quick implementation details - for use in a VF page - (once the component is built):**

You will want a structure like this:

```
VF Page (instantiate and add callback)
       DatepickerWrapper (handle date change events, call callback)
                         Datepicker (perform date display and selection)
```

In your `DatepickerWrapper` component, handle the `dateChangeEvent` from the `Datepicker` and add a callback attribute (for lightning out):

```
<aura:handler name="dateChangeEvent" event="c:DateChange" action="{!c.handleDateChange}" />
<aura:attribute name="callback" type="String" description="Call this to communicate results to visualforce page" access="global"/>
```

Place the `Datepicker` in the `DatepickerWrapper` component like this (assuming you are using slds) (you may want to do all form element stuff in the parent vf page - up to you):

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-m-top--medium">
  <c:DatePicker aura:id="closeDate" label="Close Date" placeholder="Enter a Date" value="{!v.opportunity.CloseDate}" formatSpecifier="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</div>
```

Finally, in your `DatepickerWrapper` controller or helper update your date by calling the callback on the vf page:

```
handleDateChange: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var func = cmp.get('v.callback');
    if (func){
      func({fieldName:"CloseDate",value:event.getParam("value")});
    }
}
```

How it looks:

[image: Datepicker gif]

Comment: Hi @Caspar, thanks for the datepicker. Do you plan to add a time picker as well?